# Проверка набора текста в Edit Text

Tags: java, android

Появилась необходимость отслеживать набор символов в Edit Text, так сказать, in real-time. Т.е. когда текст начали вводить, вывести в логи, и когда закончили набирать вывести в логи.

Не очень понимаю, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Повесьте на ваш EditText слушатель:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

});
```